# How to verify MetaMask wallet address belongs to user?

Tags: metamask, react

Having a bit of a road block in my development process. I want to create an application where a user signs in through metamask, and has their owned NFTs displayed.

In the MetaMask api, I found this https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html#connecting-to-metamask

```
const ethereumButton = document.querySelector('.enableEthereumButton');
const showAccount = document.querySelector('.showAccount');

ethereumButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  getAccount();
});

async function getAccount() {
  const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
  const account = accounts[0];
  showAccount.innerHTML = account;
}
```

This works great, and I am able to receive the accounts[0] with Javascript, to see the wallet address of the user.

The main issue I am having is how to verify the user owns the wallet. Am I missing a big step in the process?

Answer (score 0):

For signing using MetaMask check out [Sign in with Ethereum project](https://login.xyz/).

Don't try to build your own authentication mechanism unless you know what you are doing.